# What's the percentage of prime numbers of the form $n! - 1$ relative to the percentage of primes numbers $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I was thinking and realised than $n!-1$ is a prime number up until $n = 8$ for $n > 2$ and this seems odd to me considering how sparse prime numbers are at values this high. Is it just a coincidence or is there something special about it being one less than a product of all the numbers below and including it? Can we figure out the rate of change of the ratio of percentage of primes of form $n! - 1$ and just $n$?

Comment: The sequence of such $n$ is [A002982](https://oeis.org/A002982)  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_prime), only $52$ such $n$ are known.

Answer (score 1):

Up to $n=8$? $5!-1 = 119 = 7 \cdot 17$ is not prime. $8!-1 = 40319 = 23 \cdot 1753$.

See [OEIS sequence A002982](https://oeis.org/A002982) for the numbers $n$ for which $n!-1$ is prime.  They get sparse rather quickly.

The fact that $n! - 1$ is rather often prime for small $n$ is attributable to the fact that $n!-1$ is not divisible by any primes $\le n$.  However, it doesn't have any advantage when it comes to primes $> n$.

Answer (score 0):

For a heuristic, the probability that $n! - 1$ is prime should be the probability that a number $\alpha$ whose size is roughly $n!$ is prime given that it is not divisible by primes between $2$ and $n$.

Bayes' law then says
$$
P(\alpha\text{ prime } | \alpha \text{ not divisible by } 2, \ldots, n) = \frac{P(\alpha \text{ prime })}{P(\alpha \text{ not divisible by } 2, \ldots, n)}
$$
Merten's third theorem says that the denominator is roughly $(\exp(\gamma)\log(n))^{-1}$ where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. The numerator is (prime number theorem) roughly $1/\log(\alpha)$, so the final probability is
$$
\frac{\exp(\gamma) \log(n)}{\log(\alpha)}
$$
This is an improvement on the baseline probability of $1/\log(\alpha)$, but is still a very small number when $n$ is large, since $n$ is much smaller than $\alpha$.

Using Stirling's approxmation $\log(\alpha) \sim n \log(n) - n$
, for example, we see that the ratio looks more or less like $1/n$.

Comment: One more heuristic, the probability that this number is prime is roughly the probability that a number the size of $\exp(n)$ is prime. Since $n!$ is way bigger than $\exp(n)$, this is higher than "expected." But it's still a very low probability.